# AngularJS : $httpBackend.when() using a method for the url

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, angularjs-e2e, angular-mock

I am trying to set up and mock $httpBackEnd for e2e testing purposes as per the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/%24httpBackend). I would like to passThrough all requests when I am requesting a template. From the docs, it says that `url` parameter can be of three types `string` `function(string)` or `RegExp` and its description:

> HTTP url or function that receives the url and returns true if the url match the current definition.

**What I'm trying to do**

I would like all GET requests to `direct/views/....` and `pub/views/....` to `PassThrough()`

**What I tried**

```
var devApp = angular.module('app-dev', ['app', 'ngMockE2E']);

devApp.run(function($httpBackend){

    var isTemplateUrl = function(url){
        if(url === '/direct/views/_shell/shell' || url === '/direct/views/_shell/shell') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
//    Manually setting the url works
//    $httpBackend.whenGET('/direct/views/_shell/shell').passThrough();
//    $httpBackend.whenGET('/direct/views/home/home').passThrough();

//    Does not work
    $httpBackend.whenGET(isTemplateUrl).passThrough();
});
```

Putting a string works, put trying to use the function doesn't.

RegExp would probably be the fastest way but I don't know anything about it. If you want to give me a working RegExp I would be eternally thankful.

I know my `isTemplateUrl` function doesn't do exactly what I wanted but that's besides the point, it should still work for these two urls.

Answer (score 2):

A regex to achieve what you're trying to do would be:

```
/(direct|pub)\/views\/.*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don.t have too many urls trough, I suggest to set the Url manually
since with regex you are allowing anything like

```
direct/views/*
pub/views/*
```

Try this and see if it solves your problem.

```
var devApp = angular.module('app-dev', ['app', 'ngMockE2E']);

devApp.run(function($httpBackend){

    $httpBackend.whenGET(/^(direct|pub)\/views\/.*$/).passThrough();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw in the answer [How to mock get(id) requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538890/how-to-mock-getid-requests) that the use of a function as the url match for the methods *when**of httpbackend is valid from the version 1.3.0. If you see the doc of other versios you'll find you can't use this function.

Instead using this function, you can pass as parameter an object with the method "test". In your case this will be:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET({ test: isTemplateUrl}).passThrough();
```

Comment: Thanks for this post. It was really helpful! In my case, I wanted to pass back a specific json file depending on which user was logged in and which group role they had.  We store the users roles in $window.USER.groups.

I accomplished this using your {test: function(){}} idea as a parameter. My solution is on a GIST here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7a5889437ff131940f451a5a77b3c7a3